# Why does Maggie use "Jesus" as an exclamation while talking to Grace?

Tags: rebecca-roanhorse, the-sixth-world

In *Trail of Lightning* by Rebecca Roanhorse, when Grace is embarrassing Maggie by making comments about Kai, Maggie uses "Jesus" as an exclamation:

> She straightens up, points toward Kai. "Make her listen. She won't listen to me. But I imagine a handsome young man like you could say things to a girl that would her listen right up."
>   "Jesus, Grace," I say, embarrassed.
>   <sub>*Trail of Lightning*, chapter 22</sub>

Maggie is Diné. She grew up with her nalí, and then with Neizgháni, neither of whom presumably would have used "Jesus" as an exclamation. The only person who we see uses "Jesus" is Grace, who isn't Diné.

So why would Maggie use it here? It's not something she'd have been exposed all that much to - from what I could tell, she's only been at the bar once or twice before.

Comment: This seems somewhat specialised. Are we talking about some kind of fantasy world? In the real (British) world, I know Muslims, Jews, and Hindus who routinely say "Jesus!".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - The question makes more sense in the context of having read the book, I believe. It's set in a future post apocalyptic world where most of North America is under water. It's set in the Navajo reservation - Dinétah - where the gods and monsters of Navajo legend walk the Earth. Maggie was raised by one such legend (Neizgháni).